# How to setup tun2socks from badvpn?

Tags: linux, tunneling

I am attempting to use tun2socks/badvpn to force all traffic through the tun device, but am having some issues.  From wireshark, it appears that traffic is indeed going out properly, but not coming back in.  By that, I mean that I can see an ACK from the target server, but it appears that that ACK isn't getting processed.

I also see in the badvpn command output that the reply is not successful, socks error.  I am trying to run it again with a more verbose log level to see if it outputs anything useful.

1. completely empty iptables ruleset, INPUT, OUTPUT, and FORWARD are all ACCEPT
2. enabled ip forwarding for all interfaces and explicitly for the tun device as well as my workstation interfaces
3. created tunnel device with ip 10.0.0.1
4. setup tun2socks on 10.0.0.2 with a socks server of 127.0.0.1
5. setup routes:
   a. route add 127.0.0.1 gw <192.168.1.1> metric 50
   b. route add default gw 10.0.0.2 metric 75

Any ideas as to what I may be missing here?

Thanks,

Walter

Comment: Would you mind posting a link about tun2vpn? cant find it in google.

Comment: Oops, it is tun2socks (badvpn): https://github.com/ambrop72/badvpn

Answer (score 1):

**Here are the proper steps:**

1. First check if your DNS is a remote one or a local one `cat /etc/resolv.conf` if it's a local one like `192.168.1.1` it does not a matter but if the DNS is remote for example `208.67.222.222` you need to add a route for it (see below)
2. Connect to your ssh server

   `ssh -N -C -D 8080 user@222.x.x.222`
3. Add tun interface

   `ip tuntap add dev tun0 mode tun user <someuser>`
4. Setup the tun interface

   `sudo ifconfig tun0 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0`
5. run tun2socks

   `badvpn-tun2socks --tundev tun0 --netif-ipaddr 10.0.0.2 --netif-netmask 255.255.255.0 --socks-server-addr 127.0.0.1:1080`
6. **if your DNS is a remote one** add a route to it with a lower metric than the tun one (lower than metric on step 8)

   `route add 208.67.222.222 gw 192.168.1.1 metric 4`
7. Add a route for your ssh server **not 127.0.0.1**

   `route add 222.x.x.222 gw 192.168.1.1 metric 4`
8. Add a default route to forward everything to the tun

   `route add default gw 10.0.0.2 metric 6`

Your mistake was `127.0.0.1` i guess your ssh server is remote not running on `127.0.0.1`...